# MUnkre topology. Page no : 126 section : 20 question 3. - b).

Tags: general-topology

MUnkre topology. Page no : 126  section : 20   question 3. - b).

Let $X'$ denote a space having the same underlying set as X. Show that if
$d : X' × X' → R$ is continuous, then the topology of $X'$ is finer than the
topology of $X.$

my attempts :Let the $d \colon \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by 
$$d (\alpha, \beta) \colon= \begin{cases} 1 \ \mbox{ if } \ \alpha \neq \beta, \\ 0 \ \mbox{ otherwise;} \end{cases} $$ for all $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$. Then $d$ is of course a metric on $\mathbb{R}$.

Now let $d_1 \colon \left( \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \right) \times \left( \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \right) \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by 
$$d_1 \left( x_1 \times y_1, \ x_2 \times y_2 \right) \colon= \max \left\{ d \left( x_1, x_2 \right), \ \left\vert  y_1 - y_2 \right\vert  \right\} \ \mbox{ for all } \ x_1 \times y_1, \ x_2 \times y_2 \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}.$$
I know that this $d$ is a metric on $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$.

now  $X' = R \times R$  is finer then $ R$  hence proved

IS  its  correct or not ??

PLiz help me..

Comment: What do we know about $d$ and $X$? Is $d$ a metric defining the topology of $X$? But, why would you only attempt this for some specific $X$ and a specific $d$? That feels a bit strange.

Comment: $R\times R$ is *finer* than $R$ if every open set of of $R\times R$ is open in $R$.

Comment: That does not make sense because the underlying sets are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

Let $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be open. Assume $\operatorname{d}^{-1}(U) \neq \varnothing$.

Let $(x, y) \in \operatorname{d}^{-1}(U)$ and set $\epsilon_1 = \frac{1}{2}(b-\operatorname{d}(x, y))$

Clearly, if $(\alpha, \beta) \in B_d(x, \epsilon_1) \times B_d(y, \epsilon_1)$, then
\begin{eqnarray}
\operatorname{d}(\alpha, \beta) &\leq& \operatorname{d}(x, \alpha) + \operatorname{d}(x, y) + \operatorname{d}(y, \beta)\\
&<& \operatorname{d}(x, y) + 2\left(\frac{b-\operatorname{d}(x, y)}{2}\right) \\
\end{eqnarray}

That is,

$$\operatorname{d}(\alpha, \beta) < b$$

Similarly, set $\epsilon_2 = \frac{1}{2}(\operatorname{d}(x, y) - a)$.

Let $(\alpha, \beta) \in B_d(x, \epsilon_2) \times B_d(y, \epsilon_2)$. Assume, for the sake of contradiction, that $\operatorname{d}(\alpha, \beta) \leq a$.

Then,

\begin{eqnarray}
\operatorname{d}(x, y) &\leq& \operatorname{d}(x, \alpha) + \operatorname{d}(\alpha, \beta) + \operatorname{d}(\beta, y) \\
\operatorname{d}(x, y) &<& \operatorname{d}(x, y)-a + \operatorname{d}(\alpha, \beta) \\
&<&  \operatorname{d}(x, y)
\end{eqnarray}

Therefore, it must be the case that
$$\operatorname{d}(\alpha, \beta) > a$$

Set $\epsilon = \operatorname{min}\{\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2\}$.

Then, if $(\alpha, \beta) \in B_d(x, \epsilon) \times B_d(y, \epsilon)$,

$$a < \operatorname{d}(\alpha, \beta) < b$$
Since any open set $U$ can be written as union of some family of intervals $\{(a_i,b_i):i\in I\}$, then
$$
d^{-1}(U)=d^{-1}(\cup_{i\in I}(a_i,b_i))=\cup_{i\in I}d^{-1}((a_i,b_i))
$$
Thus $d^{-1}(U)$ is open as union of open sets

Comment: You should try to prove that $B_d(x,r)$ is open in $X'$ for all $x\in X$, $r>0$. Whether $d^{-1}(U)$ is open is irrelevant to the question. And, it is automatic from the continuity assumption anyway.

Comment: @Jyrki  sir....$A= \bigcup_{x \in X} B_{r} (x)$, where $B_r (x) = \{y \in X| d(x,y)<r$\}. Clearly $A$ is open. as  union of open set is open

Comment: Open, with respect to which topology? The task at hand is to show that $B_r(x)$, which is trivially open in $X$, is also open in $X'$. The tool you have is that $d$ is also continuous w.r.t. the topology of $X'\times X'$. This is not difficult, but it is imperative that at each step you keep an eye on the fact that there are two topologies in the set underlying $X$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen sir   can  u    answer in detail...as  i  finding  diificulty